# Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Using an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on applying a conditional in my Regions show page based on the careers that are present. I only want to show that region's careers OR the ones on the HQ.

So I put in my helper

```
def career_region
 current_career = @careers
 hq = Career.joins(:region).where(regions: {name: "HQ"})
 current_career.or(hq)
end
```

So I end up with

> Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible
>   values: [:joins]

Now I know I could do:

```
hq = Region.find_by(name: "HQ").careers
```

But this has me curious to know how I can do the joins where and then do an or by @careers.

Is there a way to do a joins where OR instance variable?

Comment: But, what's the value of `@careers`.

Comment: In this case it's the current region's list of careers since it's being used on the Region's show page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message specifies, the problem is that `@careers` relation doesn't have the `joins` with `:region`, and `hq` relation does have the `joins`. When `ActiveRecord` construct the SQL query, it will have a syntax error.

Fortunately, the fix is very simple, you just need to add the joins to `@careers`, just like this:

```
def career_region
  current_career = @careers
  hq = Career.joins(:region).where(regions: {name: "HQ"})
  current_career.joins(:region).or(hq)
end
```